# What is `wp-cli.yml` for in the public_html folder?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, cpanel, public-html

I recently signed up a hosting package, and installed WordPress from the control panel. I noticed there is `wp-cli.yml` in the web root folder. The file contains:

```
apache_modules:
    - mod_rewrite
```

Can I ask what is it for? Is it a good idea to leave it there even if I might never use it?

Comment: I have a hunch its a file that got installed from you installing wordpress. I guess this because the filename starts with wp which stands for wordpress. If I'm correct, then I'd just leave the file alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a file that your hosting company is using to help them manage the availability of and updates to the WordPress Command Line Interface. It’s supposed to be there, don’t mess with it.

Answer (score 4):

It is used by [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/), the command line interface for WordPress.
The `wp-cli.yml` is where you set configuration values, related to your website, for wp-cli.php to use.
https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/config/

For example, to [update "pretty links"](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/rewrite/flush/) from the command line (`wp rewrite flush`), the `wp-cli.yml` (or a `config.yml`) file is necessary for the command to work properly.
From the docs:

> `wp rewrite flush` flushes rewrite rules.
>   Resets WordPress’ rewrite rules based on registered post types, etc.
>   To regenerate a `.htaccess` file with WP-CLI, you’ll need to add the `mod_rewrite` module to your `wp-cli.yml` or `config.yml`.
>   For example:
>   `apache_modules:
>     - mod_rewrite`

Flushing and Re-saving permalinks is often needed when changing themes, or if you change the installation folder for your WordPress files.